# Meta Title is not showing in Joomla website for Article pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, seo

I am facing an issue where Joomla article pages are not showing 
  Tag. While it shows other meta tags as below :

Here is the URL of testing version site :
http://dev.innvonix.in/enlight/

How i can add Meta title for those pages for Article pages. I have created Menu of single article.

Can any one help me on this.
[image]

Comment: Looking at the html source of that link, I can see the tag "<title>EnlightHome - Enlightin - New concept of Customized Lamp and Lightbox</title>" which is what I'd expect I think.

Comment: Actually i am asking for <meta name="title" value=""> So meta tag with Title should cam as above per <title></title> Tag. At present it generates <title> tag but not generating <meta name="title">. So is there any settings for this in Joomla ? I have note down that for Products and category page of Virtemart, virtuemart provide additional Meta related textboxes and those page generates <meta> tag and <title> tag both.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not come across the I'd not come across the...

```
<meta name="title" value="">
```

...meta tag usage.  Thanks for explaining in the comments there.

I found a handy SO post on it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076201/difference-between-meta-name-title-tag-and-title-title-tag

In joomla this is not really provided in by default, however it'd be easy to add it to your template.

So you'd just edit your template's index.php file and put the code...

```
<?php
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
?>
<meta name="title" value="<?php echo $active->title; ?>">
```

...between the head tags.

Alternatively you could use...

```
<meta name="title" value="<?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?>">
```

...either would work fine.

This assumes you're using a fairly normal Joomla template, it may be different if your template is a gantry, helix or t3 type thing from a template shop.

There are some notes on Joomla page titles at https://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_dynamic_page_title

If you wanted to only display this tag for some components, as per your comment, you could just add a conditional.  So, to have it only show on pages that were not Virtuemart, you could do...

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$current_component = $jinput->get('option');
if ( !substr_count( $current_component, "com_virtuemart") ) {
    ?>
    <meta name="title" value="<?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?>">
    <?php
}
```

For more notes on this, see  [How to check what component is being used on current page?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4204/how-to-check-what-component-is-being-used-on-current-page)

Comment: Hello AndryGaskell, If we put your above snippest to my cost it will generate <meta name="title"> twice for few pages. Because our code will create separate <meta name="title"> for each page, while many pages of Virtuemart will provide functionality to add meta title,desc,metadata so this will not be good idea.

Comment: Hi info-truth, I've adjusted the answer with some extra details to help with this.

Comment: @InfoTruth does the amended answer now address your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would better suggest you to totally remove the `meta title tag` as it is  superfluous and a waste of code. It doesn't really add any value to the page.

Actually it shouldn't be there at all on a fresh Joomla! 3 site, as it has been removed in recent J versions, and plus there is no UI control to enable/disable it anymore. So I guess this is an older updated website, which somehow inherited this setting from your old configuration file.

To remove it, just open your configuration.php and find the corresponding variable - public `$MetaTitle = '1';` and delete it.

Comment: FFrewin, I have used latest joomla version, i have no idea about it provides support for meta title or not but i have noted down that virtuemart pages/products/category provides features to add this and those pages shows this meta details in code preview. suggest more if there is any alternative.